# Eclipse now shows only a single method in an editor pane after clicking on the method in Package Explorer view, how can I reset to normal behavior?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

In the Package Explorer of Eclipse (version Helios) you can drill down into a Java class and see its methods and members listed.  Until recently if I clicked on a method name in the Package Explorer then the entire class file would open (if not already opened) and the cursor would be at the method I just clicked on, but the entire class file would also be in the editor pane, and I could scroll up or down to any other part of the class file.  Now however when I click on a method I get an editor pane which contains only the code for that method.  If an editor pane for the class file was already opened then it gets overwritten with the code for just the method I clicked on in the Package Explorer view, and I have to close the pane and re-click on the top level class file name in order to see the entire file's contents.  Very annoying.

I'm not sure what caused this but recently I added the Aptana plugin to Eclipse which appears to have monkeyed with some of the preferences/settings so I uninstalled this plugin, assuming that I'd get back to where I was before.  Unfortunately the above issue persists, as well as a few other minor annoyances such as modified colors, etc.

Can anyone suggest how I'd go about getting the old default Package Explorer method click behavior back?  Perhaps there's some way I can go back to the settings I had before I installed the Aptana plugin?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor and *deselect* "Only show the selected Java Element".

It is a hidden preference.  I once had this happen to me in an entirely different circumstance and it took me hours to find the answer.

Comment: Same for me, I was looking for how to highlight a block based on the brace I was hovering over, in the process I clicked Only show selected Java Element, what a mistake. Thank you for this answer. I would have spent hours trying to figure out what I had done wrong.